# Removing dots from a navbar

Tags: html, css

I found this wonderful navbar online but I don't find the line in the code to remove the dots.

The current Looking: https://gyazo.com/0531847d45ebfc31d7a15b09b5404c9f
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ujzge3sg/

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
nav {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar {
    background: #f96e5b;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-fixed-top {}
.navbar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting a pancake recipe?

Comment: Also, consider showing your HTML

Comment: @Jessica I had to add more details, but there are nomore I can give.. and they are tasty..

Comment: Bypassing character requirements by adding a pancake recipe does not solve the problem.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara not awnsering my question don't solve it eather..

Comment: But if we're busy making pancakes @BennetG. How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Made a problem statement maybe, but not ask a question. Hint: You don't have a `?` character.

Comment: @FrankerZ Now it's evolving into a real Problem.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial of [list-style-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp), or in your words, those are the black dots.

Just do `list-style-type: none;` on the `li` list. It would help if you would learn `HTML` and `CSS` before asking a question about it.

**Update**

After seeing the full HTML and CSS, I saw the 'problem'. There was an `after` adding squares after every `li`. To remove the squares, just delete from line 68-78 in the JSFiddle.

Here's an updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/d7Lrartp/

Comment: Thank you.. I just want to buily myself a simple website.. No need to learn it. So I thought I may get help here...

Comment: Don't work anyways...

Comment: @BennetG. Can you show your HTML code? What do you mean by 'buily'? Also, you can create something without knowing what you're doing. Consider using wix or godaddy

Comment: [link](http://hastebin.com/huyiwojeso.xml) Here's the HTML @Jessica

Comment: JSFiddle, or codepen are meant for sharing code. In your css code do: `li {list-style-type: none;}`.

Comment: Added JSFiddle.. Just look in the Question

Comment: @BennetG. So is it fixed?

Comment: I don't see any dots. What is the problem?

Comment: The Big dots on the right of every li are the problem.. I don't get the way to remove them..

Comment: https://gyazo.com/3f57866f4f44b4622abe54e4d10de2d5 Those

Comment: @BennetG. Oh. I see it now. I had to make the size bigger. Just remove the `.navbar ul li a:after` thing. From line 68-78 in the JSFiddle. Here's an updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/d7Lrartp/

Comment: Thank you very much.. It wasn't that easy that I expected.. :D

Comment: Can You post it in a extra Anwser, so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: @BennetG. Done. Updated the answer